# Kafka Connect: How can I read/access properties from the connect-distributed.properties from my custom SMT?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Kafka Connect JDBC Source Connector and a custom SMT.
I want to access the truststore and keystore locations and their respective passwords from the connect-distributed.properties file. For e.g the below section:

```
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/myapp/config/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=mypassword
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/myapp/config/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=mypassword
ssl.key.password=mypassword
```

How can I achieve inside my SMT? This is more inclined towards the below section:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
KAFKA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${CERTS_PATH}/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${CERTS_PATH}/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -Djavax.net.ssl.keyPassword=$KEY_PASSWORD"
```

If I do not put the above, the the Schema Registry call from my custom SMT, throws bad_certificate exception.
I know I can set these properties as part of ConfigDef, but then it would not be nice to expose the credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your transform shouldn't need these files. It's running under the same JVM as the connect worker, which would already be authenticated.

Your SMT also should only with with Struct/Schema objects, not the Converter or Serializer classes that operate with the Regsistry HTTP client.